# Can I count the total number of tests without executing them?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4

Using maven, is there a way to count the total number of tests intended to be run, without actually running them?

Comment: I also could not find it using maven. No need to mention that performing global search for @Test word using exact match case and with file mask as *.java in Intellij would tell us.

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: very very basic test coverage stats